# How do I set a Dynamic Choice Field using a Model field in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

How can I use 'Dynamic Choices' generated from another Model field? I would like to add a new choice to a field called `color` without editing code/tuple. The example below demonstrations what I have already tried, but in this example 'choices' doesn't expect a model to be used so this will not work! Is this possible, if so what would be the best approach?

```
class Furniture(models.Model):
     color = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FurnitureChoices)


class FurnitureChoices(models.Model):
      color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

It is not the FK to the model I'm interested in, but the ability to allow users to add additional choices themselves.

Comment: You can create a separate `Color` model and add it as a foreign key in `Furniture` model.

Comment: Updated my OP and it really about  the ability to allow users to add additional choices themselves to Furniture colour

Comment: So you want to associate multiple colors to a `Furniture` instance such that users can select color from choices as well as add a new color if color they desire is not available in the current choices. Am I getting your problem correctly?

Comment: One approach: Create `Furniture`, `Color` and `FurnitureColor` models. Add to `FurnitureColor` FKs to `Furniture` and `Color`. Now you create a form which 3 fields: one to select `Furniture`, one to select `Color`,  and one `CharField` to input a color. In views, depending on which fields were selected in the form, you can create a new color and then create a new `FurnitureColor` using that color.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ForeignKey.

```
class Furniture(models.Model):
     color = models.ForeignKey(FurnitureChoices)


class FurnitureChoices(models.Model):
      color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
class FurnitureChoices(models.Model):
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('R', 'Red'),
        ('B', 'Blue'),
     )
    color = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
```